# Is there a way to export ag-grid to excel ignoring the grouping on rows(grouping on a single column)?

Tags: reactjs, excel, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is there a way to export ag-grid to excel ignoring the grouping on rows(grouping on a single column) ?

I'm receiving the data from API, and showing it by grouping on a single column. But while exporting it to excel I want the raw data to be making the excel. Is there a way possible/currently available in ag-agid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the property `skipGroups` (see [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/react/export/#selecting-data-to-export)) to `true` on the export params.

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Kdq7qKUVNkTEtce0).

Comment: Thanks, But actually I'm using --
{
headerName: "name",
field: "name",
rowGroup: true,
hide: true,
},

to group directly on name column rather than showing an additional col as Group. While using skipGroups: true, it shows name column empty which is bad, I want to get the raw json data like format to create the excel(without any grouping).

Comment: set the property `allColumns` to true when exporting (see documentation from my answer).